# Why is my Dell Vostro 3500 overheating?  The internal temperature is around 75 C

Tags: laptop, cooling, multi-core

I felt that my Vostro laptop is overheating.  I downloaded a tool named SpeedFan to test my internal laptop temperature.  Speedfan gives the following measurements:

```
Temp1: 75 C
Core0: 70 c
Core1: 71 c
```

1. Are the measurements good, or does the laptop have a problem?
2. What is the best way to reduce the laptop temperature?

I always put the laptop on a table when using it, for better air flow.

Comment: This really belong on SuperUser, rather than ServerFault.

Comment: I agree with HopelessN00b, this is not the place for these types of questions.

Answer (score 4):

If this is the temperature under load, it's quite normal. If not then it's a bit on the high side. First thing to do is to dust the fans out, when dust gathers on the fan the airflow is worse and the cooling element can't give off enough heat.

To dust out your fan, just open the fan cover and use an airduster to clean it out. Be sure to lock the fan in place so it doesn't start spinning (you might break it otherwise).
[image]

If a table isn't working you can buy a special laptop cooler. It is a plastic pad that tilts the laptop and has some extra fans on the bottom.
[image]

Comment: By "lock the fan in place", is there an actual way to do that or should you just push something up against the blades so they don't spin?  That what I always do.

Comment: No you have to hold it manually, pushing it is not good, preferable use a wooden toothpick and stick it between the blades, hold it while you spray it.

Comment: That's what I meant, yeah - hold something against the blades.  You got my hopes up that laptop fans had a switch or something that locked the fan so you could clean it.

Comment: No that would just cause a lot of overheating laptops because people forget to switch it off :p

Answer (score 2):

My Vostro 3500 was at 75 - 78C. CPU load is 33% and I am not doing anything with my computer. I checked the Task Manager, selected to show all users process and found that the Digital Persona (the fingerprint reader) was using 28% of the load. I killed the process and overheating is gone. Now is in a 45 to 55C range. I will follow instructions to clean the fan.

Hope this helps.